# Tizen App : processing result : FATAL_ERROR

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Tizen App stops execution with error :

```
processing result : FATAL_ERROR [61] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [293962]ms
cmd_ret:61
Unexpected stop progress...
```

What could be the possible work around for Error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you've tried to install "wearable 2.3" app (perhaps, some sample app?) to real device.

Please try to change the "required_version" in your config.xml to 2.2. At least, it worked for me with Gear S real device.

PS: Found following link in Tizen's JIRA: https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/browse/TIVI-1436. Perhaps discussion in comments will clarify things a bit for you. I mean, what a mess is going on behind **that curtain** ;)

Comment: dude, you're a life saver. I was so frustrated with this Tizen IDE until I finally found your answer!

Comment: Here at work, we're considering developing a custom build system, just so we don't have to use this pesky IDE anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same error on Tizen phones using 2.3rev0.  I found the cause was actually pretty simple - I did the bonehead move of not actually loading the cert on the device.  My fix was:

1) Open connection explorer in the Tizen IDE

2) Plug your device in via USB, wait until it is recognized

3) Right click on your device

4) Select the bottom option "Permit to install applications"

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: How do you do "Permit to install applications" in Tizen Studio 2.0 ??

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error exactly after building a package with Tizen Studio version 1.0.1.  Tried installing native app (Debug Build) from Tizen samples.  First started HD Mobile M-2.3.1, got to this error, then started M-2.3, both the same FATAL_ERROR[61].  Tried HD Mobile M-2.4, right-clicked on project and selected Run As -> Tizen Native Applicaiton.  It Worked!   Mind you, same steps on the other versions of Tizen OS failed with error, I tried copying the command it ran into the shell, got FATAL_ERROR [61], exactly like the one you are talking about.

Take away:  the steps you are taking to test your app are good; the version of emulator, somehow, does not match the build of the app.

You can try:
 1. another version of the emulator
 2. Figuring out how to build your app more generically.  There is a tizen-manifest.xml for the sample apps, and Api Version can be changed.

If I had to guess, I'd say you seeded your code from latest sample that only works on latest Tizen platform.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tizen 2.4 SDK.

If you are building Tizen2.3 web app which was imported, you may face this problem. For that create a new Tizen project and then copy all file accordingly.

If SDK is Tizen2.3, then update to the latest one and set permission for installing app by right clicking the device in connection manager.